# List tags by certain letter issue with special chars like å, ä and ö

Tags: tags

I'm trying to list tags from a specific letter. It works from a-z but not special chars like **å, ä and ö** which we have here in Sweden.

`mb_substr()` doesn't seem to solve the problem. I have double checked that the encoding is right in the document (UTF8) and that `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>` is set in the head.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>Ö</h3>
    </li>
    <?php
    $tags = get_tags( array('name__like' => "ö", 'order' => 'ASC') );
    foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
        if( strtolower( mb_substr( $tag->name,0,1 ) ) !='ö' ){ continue; } ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) ?>">
                <?php echo $tag->name ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

How can this be solved?

Kind regards

Johan

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code is working, its just hiding the empty tags. So you better populate the tags named with **å, ä and ö** or you can add the line `hide_empty => false` to the argument. And then the code will be like below-

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h3>Ö</h3>
    </li>
    <?php
    $tags = get_tags(
        array(
            'name__like'    => "ö",
            'order'         => 'ASC',
            'hide_empty'    => false // It will show the empty tags.
        )
    );
    foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
        if( strtolower( mb_substr( $tag->name, 0, 1 ) ) != 'ö' ){ continue; } ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_tag_link( $tag->term_id ) ?>">
                <?php echo $tag->name ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

> This above code is tested.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry your code seems not to work for me. I have posts with tags that starts with "å", "ä" and "ö" in their name. They never show up. If i change to another char like "g" mine and your codes works. I assume there is maybe an encoding problem involved for me, since it seems to work for you?

Comment: Mine is also set to `UTF-8`. The line is `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.